# Interfacing with C library, why does this not work (strcpy, std::string, char *)?

Tags: c++, c++11

I am writing a program that needs to interface with an external C library. I have to pass
a char* parameter to a function, to get a name of a data set. Essentially the situation look
like below

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

#include <string.h>

void give_name(char* name) {
    const char* name_test = "test";
    strcpy(name, name_test);
}

int main() {
    std::string a;
    a.reserve(10);
    char b[10];
    give_name(&a[0]);
    give_name(b);
    std::cout << a << std::endl;
    std::cout << b << std::endl;
}
```

Now, I am stumped, why `a` does not contain `"test"` in my example and instead is empty:

```
ASM generation compiler returned: 0
Execution build compiler returned: 0
Program returned: 0

test
```

The above was compiled with gcc12.2 with `-std=c++11`.

I even looked in the inside of the "give_name" function with gdb (in the real library
and not a simple example above), and there the variable corresponding to `name` contains proper text.

I feel like I am missing something important, any help? Even funnier that this works in different place of the code? Is this the *mythical undefined behaviour*?

Comment: Please note that [`reserve`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/reserve) doesn't change the *size* of a `string`. You could use [`resize`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/resize) or the constructor `std::string a(10, '\0');`.

Comment: `give_name(&a[0]);` There isn't even an `a[0]` at this point. The string is empty, so any index is out-of-bounds.

Comment: Also, to assign a value to `a` you just have to do `a = "test"`.

Comment: Also note that you can use [`a.data()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/data) instead of `&a[0]`;

Comment: Minor point: `give_name` (as written; obviously might have been simplified for the question) doesn't need `name_test`. `strcpy(name, "test");` works just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you reserved storage in `a` to give it a capacity of 10, its size is still zero. You are not supposed to modify the string buffer like this.

The stream output for `std::string` will write the characters up to its known end of string, *not* the NUL-terminator if you happened to break the rules. So you might see your "expected" result if you do:

```
std::cout << a.data() << std::endl;
```

But that is a super bad idea. You have already broken the string, and it cannot fulfill its behavioral guarantees as per the standard.

In general it's not recommended to write NUL-terminated strings directly into a `std::string` buffer. But if you do, you should calculate the new length and `resize` the string accordingly.

Comment: Why is it *"not recommended to write NUL-terminated strings directly into a std::string buffer"*?

Comment: I meant in the case where the string being written is a shorter than the string currently stored. The OP is expecting the string to dynamically compute its size. Of course you can write whatever you want in there, but not leave the string in a state where its contract is broken.

Comment: @paddy -- in case it isn't clear, embedded `nul` characters are perfectly okay in `std::string` objects. `std::string a = "abcd"; a[1] = '\0';` Now, `a` holds four characters: `'a'`, `'\0'`, `'c'`, and `'d'`. `std::cout << a;` would show all four; std::cout << a.str();` would show only the `'a'`, because it's streaming a C-style string, i.e., a nul-terminated string.

Comment: Hmm. I would tweak the wording then. Currently it reads like you'd never recommend it.

Comment: I don't personally recommend it, but I can see that's a controversial opinion. I use `std::vector` to do stuff like that, along with `std::string_view`. I know you can shove whatever data you like into the string, but at that point you're treating it more like binary data than a string. Of course there's times when you wanna do some processing in-place and the buffer happens to already be a string. Do you think that's appropriate for beginners? I don't.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I fixed it by resizing first ta known size (I know what is the biggest possible label size from the external library) and than resizing to `strlen(a.data())`.
the last question I have: if this is not the best way to do things, what is the best way to get strings from C libraries that accept `char *` as arguments to functions? Pass a temporary `char` array and than construct a string from that?

Comment: It's probably too convoluted to do that, and I'll need to backtrack on my hard-line stance! It's fine for you to do it. Just consider that a well-behaved C interface that allows a caller to supply a buffer for writing should generally _also_ include a parameter that specifies the size of that buffer. Unless it's documented very clearly what the minimum buffer size is required to be. You might also want to have the function return a string length or something as a courtesy to the caller, if it's useful.

Answer (score 1):

function reserve() does not change size of string. It just allocates memory. You can use method resize() instead of reserve().

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

#include <string.h>

void give_name(char* name) {
    const char* name_test = "test";
    strcpy(name, name_test);
}

int main() {
    std::string a;
    a.resize(10);
    char b[10];
    give_name(&a[0]);
    give_name(b);
    std::cout << a << std::endl;
    std::cout << b << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: a.size() is 10, but it should be 4. you need to resize to null termination after the give_name call.

Answer (score 1):

An `std::string` stores the current contents size as a `std::size_t` data member, while a C-String is terminated by a Null character. You need to use `resize` instead of `reserve` and you must shrink the `std::string` after calling the C function, so that its size fits the position of the Null terminator character.

Note that the string-buffer inside `std::string` has a length of `string.size() + 1`, because a `std::string`'s buffer is also always Null terminated. Your C array `b` has a buffer of 10 characters, your `std::string` `a` has a buffer of 11 characters!

To resize after your C function call you can use `std::string.find('\0')`. If your C function did anything as expected, this will always return a value less your buffer size. You might use `std::min` with the string size to make sure a bug in your C function doesn't break your program. (If '\0' is not found, `find` will return an extremely large value!) If you do this, you should also explicitly rewrite the null terminator, because `resize` might not do this, if the `std::string`'s size doesn't change.

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <string.h>

void give_name(char* name) {
    const char* name_test = "test";
    strcpy(name, name_test);
}

int main() {
    std::string a;
    a.resize(10);
    give_name(a.data());
    a.resize(std::min(a.find('\0'), a.size()));
    a[a.size()] = '\0'; // valid because internal data size == size() + 1
    std::cout
        << "      a: " << a << '\n'
        << "a.c_str: " << a.c_str() << '\n'
        << " a.size: " << a.size() << '\n';

    char b[10];
    give_name(&b[0]);
    std::cout << "\n      b: " << b << '\n';
}
```

```
      a: test
a.c_str: test
 a.size: 4

      b: test
```

Note that this usage of `std::string` as a C string buffer is possible, but as you can see not a trivial task! Its simple to do it wrong. So be careful.

---

**You can avoid these pitfalls by using the following wrapper class when calling a C style function:**

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

class out_c_str{
public:
    out_c_str(std::string& target, std::size_t const buffer_size)
        : target_(target)
    {
        target_.resize(buffer_size);
    }

    out_c_str(out_c_str const&) = delete;

    ~out_c_str() {
        target_.resize(std::min(target_.find('\0'), target_.size()));
        target_[target_.size()] = '\0';
    }

    operator char*() noexcept {
        return target_.data();
    }

private:
    std::string& target_;
};

int main() {
    std::string a;
    give_name(out_c_str(a, 10));
    std::cout
        << "      a: " << a << '\n'
        << "a.c_str: " << a.c_str() << '\n'
        << " a.size: " << a.size() << '\n';
}
```

```
      a: test
a.c_str: test
 a.size: 4
```

Answer (score 0):

You are only allowed to modify the characters that are actually part of the string.  You would expect `reserve` to save some memory for new characters, but that's not guaranteed by the standard - that memory is technically not part of the string.  What you're doing is undefined behavior.

You can use `resize` instead of `reserve`, but then you need to resize the string again when you're done.  It's not necessarily UB, but it's still kind of dodgy.

It's possible to create a temporary object that presents an actual C array to your function, then copies the result to your string in its destructor.

```
template<size_t MAX_SIZE>
class buffer
{
    char buf[MAX_SIZE+1];
    std::string & result;
    public:
    buffer(std::string & str) : buf{0}, result(str)
    {
        // optional if you want to initialize with the existing string contents
        //strncpy(buf, str.c_str(), MAX_SIZE);
    }
    ~buffer()
    {
        result = buf;
    }
    operator char*(void)
    {
        return buf;
    }
};

int main() {
    std::string c;
    give_name(buffer<10>(c));
    std::cout << c << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

[See it in action](https://ideone.com/A81E0C)